# Scoping disposables

Tags: c#, ninject, idisposable

Given an assembly where I'd have a `SomeContext` class derived from `DbContext` and implementing interface `ISomeContext`, and a `SomeService` class implementing `ISomeService` interface, I'd bind the rest of the app's dependencies like this:

```
kernel.Bind(t => t.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .Where(c => !c.Name.EndsWith("Context") && !c.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                  .BindAllInterfaces());
```

Then, given that `SomeService` has a constructor-injected `ISomeContext` dependency, with *Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope* I can define a named scope like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>().DefinesNamedScope("ServiceScope");
```

And then when I say `SomeContext` lives in the named scope I've just created, like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeContext>().To<SomeContext>().InNamedScope("ServiceScope");
```

My understanding is that by doing that, whenever an instance of `SomeService` gets injected, the `SomeContext` instance that it received in its constructor will only live for as long as the `SomeService` instance exists - that is, when `SomeService` gets garbage collected, `SomeContext` gets disposed and dies gracefully.

...I have a few questions:

- Is this the proper way of scoping a class that implements `IDisposable`?

  - If not, then what would be a proper way of scoping a class that is disposable?
- If `SomeService` is injected in another class (turns out it actually is!), doesn't that other class somewhat creates a *scope* the context lives and dies in? If so, then what's the use of declaring a "named scope" if all it does is give a name to what gets disposed at garbage collection time?

  - Shortly put, how exactly is the above code ultimately different from not specifying a scope at all?

Note: *InRequestScope* is irrelevant here, I'm not talking about a Web app. The application is in fact a class library that gets composed when a client VB6 library calls into it; the C# code lives as a global instance in the VB6 library, and the entire C# app gets composed at once. If the context/disposables live for as long as the C# app's global VB6 instance exists, there's something I'm doing wrong - I'd like my connections to be as short-lived as possible, so I believe I can't be injecting contexts just like this, I should instead be injecting factories that spit out a context that only lives for as long as it is needed, and that would be the scope of whoever gets that factory injected... I think I've just answered part of my question here... have I?

Comment: Hint: Ninject periodically (every 30 seconds) check's whether it's weak-references to the scope are alive. That means, that objects in the scope may outlive the scope for quite a while. If you need your scoped objects to be disposed when the scope gets disposed, implement INotifyWhenDisposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not using a scope, ninject will not call `IDispose.Dispose()` on the Context.
- .InParentScope() on the context makes sure the context is disposed when the object it gets injected into (`SomeService`) gets garbage collected
- --> When `SomeService` implements `INotifyWhenDisposed`, the context will get disposed immediately after `SomeService` gets disposed.
- .InNamed scope is good for injecting the same instance of the Context into multiple objects of an object tree.

[image: No Scope vs. Named Scope object references]

Also see http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/12/08/how-to-use-the-additional-ninject-scopes-of-namedscope/